# Logout user when disabled in AD

Tags: adfs, aspnetboilerplate

We have configured ASP.NET Zero MVC + jQuery application to work with AD FS login.

We cannot figure out if a person is currently login to website and we disable the person's account in Active Directory then how can we logout the user from website so that he cannot access website anymore.

I'm new to AD and AD FS, can anyone please guide me to a starting point?

Comment: you are going to have to send a request to AD to check for the status of the user's account.  that in itself is not hard using Directory services, but you will have to decide how often you need or want to do this polling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - as per @John, AD access and manipulation is via LDAP calls via the .NET AD API.

This is not part of ADFS.

If the AD account is disabled, the user won't be able to login once their session has expired.

In terms of the website, you would need to monitor AD and then clear the cookies (which is what logout does) as appropriate.